# Send flag to finish an activity from any other class

Tags: android, android-activity, broadcastreceiver, bundle

I have a class (Not an Activity) that has a stack of activities in background. Some times, I want to close an old activity from that stack, but most of the times the activities are so in background that if I use `finish()`, it doesn't work.

So, I was thinking on using `putExtra` to send the message to that activity so it can close on the `onResume()`.

I'm trying to do it this way without success:

On my NoActivity.class:

```
public void removeActivityFromStack(Activity activity){
    for(int i = mActivityStack.size(); i>0; i--){
        if(mActivityStack.get(i - 1).equals(activity)){
            mActivityStack.remove(i-1);
            activity.getIntent().putExtra(CLOSE_ACTIVITY, true);
        }
    }
}
```

And on the `MyActivity`.class:

```
@Override
protected void onResume() {
    super.onResume();
    Bundle bundle = getIntent().getExtras();
    if(bundle != null && bundle.getBoolean(getString(R.string.bundle_cerrar_activity), false)){
        this.finish();
    }
}
```

Any help will be appreciated.

---

I also tried using `BroadcastReceiver` to close those activities, but it still doesn't work. I tried the next way:

On my NoActivity.class

```
    public void removeActivityFromStack(Activity activity){
        for(int i = mActivityStack.size(); i>0; i--){
            if(mActivityStack.get(i - 1).equals(activity)){
                IntentFilter filter = new IntentFilter();
                CloseActivitiesBroadcastReceiver baseActivityReceiver = new CloseActivitiesBroadcastReceiver();
                filter.addAction(CLOSE_ACTIVITY);
                current.registerReceiver(baseActivityReceiver, filter);
                current.sendBroadcast(new Intent(CLOSE_ACTIVITY));
                mActivityStack.remove(i-1);
            }
        }
    }
```

And on CloseActivitiesBroadcastReceiver.java:

```
public class CloseActivitiesBroadcastReceiver extends BroadcastReceiver {
    @Override
    public void onReceive(Context context, Intent intent) {
        if (intent.getAction().equals(context.getString(R.string.bundle_cerrar_activity))) {
            ((Activity)context).finish();
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: @Ragu Swaminathan nope, not with BroadcasterReceiver unfortunatelly. Just with a dirty way. I can put the way I did as an answer while nobody gives me a better solution

Comment: what is the exact problem you are facing

Comment: "most of the times the activities are so in background that if I use finish(), it doesn't work" isn't that clearly enough?

Comment: Let me confirm whether i'm correct. Activity 1 and Activity 2 are running. Then you send broadcast message to finish the Activity 1 from some other  Activity say Activity 3. ? is it correct

Comment: not exactly. The one that sends the broadcast message is not an activity, is a Singleton that manages the activityStack. The problem is, when I have too many activities open, when I do activity.finish() the first activities in the stack (the older ones) doesnt excecute the finish()

Comment: so the activity will be running anyway ?

Comment: exactly. If i press the back button, the activity that should be closed, resumes anyway

Comment: you need to register the running activity to the broadcast receiver and then send the broadcast with the help of key.

Comment: I actually did, as you can see in my second approach. The problem is that is not working either. I suppose that if I try to assign the broadcaster when the activity is in background, wont do anything (for the same reason the activity cant excecute finish() ). But if I try to assign the broadcaster when I create the activity, an exception occurs cause I'm not able to asign the same Broadcaster to multiples activities

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Okay, this is a Little dirty answer, but is the only one that I could make work. If somebody gets a better answer, post it.

On my NoActivity.class:

```
public void removeActivityFromStack(Activity activity){
    for(int i = 0; i<mActivityStack.size(); i++){
        if(mActivityStack.get(i).equals(activity)){
            activity.finish()
            mActivityStack.remove(i);
        }
    }
}
```

This way, if the activity is in foreground, will close on `finish()`. Else, it won't close at all. But for this case:

On the MyActivity.class:

```
    @Override
    protected void onResume() {
        super.onResume();
        if(!mNoActivityInstance.getActivityStack().contains(this)){
            finish();
        }
    }
```

In my case, NoActivity.class works as a Singleton

Answer (score 0):

Try to use broadcast receiver in your activity to finish,
1) Register activity to listen for finish event.
2) Send broadcast which will be received by the activity and it will finish it self.

Hope this will help to resolved your issue.

thanks

Comment: thanks for your answer. can you explain me how can I do that?